# Is there a way of setting the parameter through a join when deploying code or other way?

Tags: sql, database, join

I want to pass a parameter through my sql statement

```
EXAMPLE: LEFT OUTER JOIN tblTable2 ON tblTable2.sitenum = tblTable1.sitenum
AND table2.ID = @ID
```

Rather than through a where clause - this is because all data relating to table1 is lost and it just returns data from table 2.

I want to get all sitenums from table 1 (has list of all site nums) and compare it to the sitenums in table 2 which have an ID. I then only want it to return all sitenums from table 1 which don't have an ID in table 2!

Answer (score 0):

You could still do this in the where clause, you just need to cater for the possibility of the null rows from table2.

`(table2.ID = @ID OR table2.ID IS NULL)`

should do the job in your where clause.